# GroovyConsole I/O

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I am starting a project to read a file of student grades and do some calculations on that information. But I cannot even manage to find syntax that would allow for the user to input a file name. I found this example but it throws an error.

```
class main
{
    static void main(args)
    {
        print ("Enter the name of the file: ");
        def fileName = System.console().readLine;
        println(fileName);
    }
}
```

[image: This is the console output.]

Comment: `readLine` is a function (you need to call it: `readLine()`)

Answer (score 0):

As @cfrick is already mentioned in the comment, `readLine` is a function/method (you need to call it properly `readLine()`) Here is the working code:

```
class Main
{
    static void main(args)
    {
        print ("Enter the name of the file: ");
        def fileName = System.console().readLine();
        println(fileName);
    }
}
```

You may read more about calling Groovy methods [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_methods.htm).

Comment: There is no error now, but I still cannot type in the console. I am using the groovy swing editor to run and write the scripts. I am not sure if that means I can't type or what